# Compiler error regarding Boost file ONLY when trying to use Instruments in Xcode 7.1

Tags: c++, boost, xcode7, instruments

I get a `Boost circular buffer file not found` issue when trying to profile my C++ code in Xcode 7.1 but no such error when running the code normally.

[image]

Do I need to pass some parameters to the Profile section in `Edit Scheme`?

[image]

EDIT:

I should add that in the same project `#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>` doesn't give an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `Instruments` always uses the latest SDK, even when the main project doesn't.

I solved the issue by including `boost framework` in the proper place within latest SDK.

Comment: great, which one, and where you've got boost.framework?