# How may I change the SDK associated with the OS X 'Instruments' app?

Tags: sdk, xcode7, instruments, juce

How may I (if it's even possible) change the `SDK` Xcode's associated `Instruments` app uses?

### Background

I am building a `VST` synth with [Juce](http://www.juce.com/) and want to profile it in OS X `Instruments`.  However, I [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505170/compiler-error-regarding-boost-file-only-when-trying-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) found out that Instruments uses the latest OS X SDK by default but my synth will not show up in the host `Ableton Live` due to a framework [bug](http://www.juce.com/forum/topic/coreimageframework-not-found-after-xcode-7-upgrade) which is solved by using an SDK less than `10.11`.  I therefore wish to choose say `10.10` SDK for Instruments to enable Profiling.

Comment: Maybe set up OS X 10.10 and Xcode 6 on an external drive and use that for profiling work ?

Comment: @PaulR Yes!  That could be the solution I think, unless I can somehow solve the problem in the Juce forum link.  Thanks for the idea

Comment: Upgrading to El Capitan fixes this issue, though that doesn't answer the question, which I suppose has no solution